# MySQL - Joining two SELECT statements that have aliases and joins inside them

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I join on A.ID_Number and B.ID_Number when both of those have their own aliases and table references inside their own select statements? The last line is currently incorrect and I need to know how to fix that.

```
SELECT*FROM
(SELECT b.ID_Number, b.Price, s.Quantity FROM tbl_bills b
 LEFT JOIN tbl_stock s ON b.Price = s.Price)
AS X

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT c.ID_Number, c.Currency, p.Purchased FROM tbl_currency c
WHERE blahblahblah)
AS Y

ON X.b.ID_Number = Y.c.ID_Number
```

There might be a better way to do the whole statement, but I only want to know how to do the last line properly, as my actual query is a lot, lot longer.

EDIT: Problem solved.

Comment: Keep in mind that your derived tables (X and Y) end up behaving like regular tables. It would be the same as if you had selected X and Y into temp tables first, and then tried to join those temp tables.

Comment: `WHERE blahblahblah` is not helping get your question answered.  Post actual code, get actual answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only use the aliases you defined . . . `X` and `Y`.  Here is an example throughout the query:

```
SELECT x.ID_Number, x.Price, x.Quantity, y.ID_Number, y.Currency, y.Purchased
FROM (SELECT b.ID_Number, b.Price, s.Quantity
      FROM tbl_bills b LEFT JOIN
           tbl_stock s
           ON b.Price = s.Price
     ) X LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.ID_Number, c.Currency, p.Purchased
      FROM tbl_currency c
      WHERE blahblahblah
     ) Y
     ON X.ID_Number = Y.ID_Number;
```

Note that `p.purchased` still has the same error, of the unrecognized column name.

To me, this is a silly way to write the query.  I would instead use:

```
SELECT b.ID_Number, b.Price, s.Quantity, c.Currency, p.Purchased  -- c.ID_Number, is not needed unless you want to see if there is a match
FROM tbl_bills b LEFT JOIN
     tbl_stock s
     ON b.Price = s.Price LEFT JOIN
     tbl_currency c
     ON b.ID_Number = c.ID_Number AND blahblahblah;
```

This is shorter, easier to write, easier to read, and should have better performance no subqueries are being materialized.

Comment: This is correct. My oversimplification of my code for the sake of the question missed another crucial error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to leave off the `b.` and `c.`:

```
ON X.ID_Number = Y.ID_Number
```

Answer (score 2):

Table names and aliases from a subquery are not visible to the main query. Just refer to the column names.

```
ON X.ID_Number = Y.ID_Number
```

Comment: It shouldn't do that. Can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Gordon Linoff is arguably the best MySQL expert here, and he also thinks this should work.

Comment: You're not wrong. I understand that your solution and Gordon's is correct, but I might have some other inconsistencies causing this issue. I believe my simplified fake code does not properly replicate the issue.

Comment: I suspect you have another level of nesting that you're not showing us. Post the real code.

Comment: The real code has sensitive info I'd rather not post. That being said, the problem has been corrected with the information I've received here. I removed column aliases in the nested Select commands and I passed them in the top select command instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT b.ID_Number, b.Price, s.Quantity, c.Currency
FROM tbl_bills b
    LEFT JOIN tbl_stock s USING (Price)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_currency c
        ON c.ID_Number = b.ID_Number AND { other criteria goes here }
```

To get any more specific you'd need to post your actual query.

To address your update *"If I try X.ID_Number = Y.ID_Number, I am given the error "Unknown column 'X.ID_Number in 'on clause'"* - the only reason that would happen is if your actual query is different than what you posted.  People are providing answers based on the code you posted.  It's important that you select `ID_Number` in both of your subqueries and the join will work.